# CHtmlView printout differs from IE printout

Tags: internet-explorer, mfc, webbrowser-control

We have a MFC application based on a CHtmlView (the WebBrowser control). When we print the content via our program, it looks different to when we save the content to a file and print it with IE.

To be more specific, we use the `page-break-inside: avoid;` as a style for a table. It works in IE, so why not in our program?

I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720%28v=vs.85%29.aspx about feature controls, but I am not sure if this has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: Feature control usually helps solving rendering issues, it should help with printing too. You can use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive for it, it doesn't require admin rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`page-break-inside` is a CSS feature added to IE8. By default, non-browser applications run in IE7 compatibility mode. Set the `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` feature control key for your application to take advantage of IE8+ features (assuming that the user has IE8+ installed, of course).

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work. Maybe I need to use a special document type?

Comment: Now it works. I used the wrong key, needed to add it under `Wow6432Node`!